# VM Install : virt-install stuck at Domain state after install: 1

Tags: kvm

I am trying to use `virt-install` to install VM on linux using `kvm` with below command. But it gets stuck at

```
Domain state after install: 1

$ sudo virt-install --virt-type=kvm --name rhel7-"$buildid" --ram 2048 --vcpus=3 --os-variant=rhel7.0\
  --cdrom="$buildlocalpath"/ssg-rhel-7.7.iso  --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0,keymap=en-us\
  --disk path=xyz,size=49,bus=ide,format=qcow2 --noautoconsole --wait=-1 --noreboot -d
```

Can anyone help here with what could be possible issue ?

Comment: Can you install the VM via `virt-manager`? Just curious if you get the same error(s).

Comment: installed virt-manager but same issue.

Comment: ignore previous comment..
looks actually it has solved the issue. now its failing with some other error - need to investigate in detail

Comment: so to conclude here.. that virt-manager installtion did not help.

Answer (score 2):

You ran virt-install with `--wait -1` which means 'wait forever until the VM exits', and `--noautoconsole` which means 'do not launch virt-viewer/virsh console to see guest output'. So what is likely happening if the your VM is sitting at the distro installer waiting for you to click 'Forward' or enter input but you aren't connected to the VM. So there's a few fixes:

- If you are running that on your local host with graphical access, drop --noautoconsole and you'll get a virt-viewer window connected to the VM
- If you are running that command on a remote host, try connecting to that remote host with `virt-manager --connect qemu+ssh://root@HOSTNAME/system' and then connecting to the VM graphical console to continue the install